# How to use a generic object flexibly?

Tags: java, android

I would like to replace the `SharedPreferences` in my Android app by a class called `SecurePreferences` (which is a modified version of [this](https://github.com/sveinungkb/encrypted-userprefs)). How can I flexibly call the methods of one of their instances?

Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SecurePreferences securePref = new SecurePreferences(sharedPref, "", key, true);
...
public void loadSettings() {
    Object pref;
    if (Settings.usingEncryptedPreferences) {
        pref = securePref;
    } else {
        pref = sharedPref;
    }
    boolean musicEnabled = pref.getBoolean("musicEnabled", true);
    boolean soundEnabled = pref.getBoolean("soundEnabled", true);
    boolean vibrationEnabled = pref.getBoolean("vibrationEnabled", true);
    // and so on
}
```

Both `SharedPreferences` and `SecurePreferences` have a `getBoolean` method. But Android Studio tells me `Cannot resolve method 'getBoolean(Java.lang.String, boolean)'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the type of your pref variable. Object class does not have getBoolean method. There can be numerous solutions. For example: If the SecurePreferences extends SharedPreferences interface (or implements it), then the type of pref variable should be SharedPreferences.